# How to set '/*' rout in codeigniter 3.x

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to rout all the request to one function

```
eg : $route['products/*'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';
```

so if I request

```
products/abc
```

or

```
products/xyz/akj/
```

or

```
products/1027/01/12
```

or

```
products/.....
```

all this case I need to trigger "catalog/product_lookup"

inside product_lookup I need to get the routs after products

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$route[‘products/(.*)’] = “products/product_lookup”;
```

Here I assume that you request `domain.com/products/product-name` and it will map in `products` which is a controller, `product_lookup` which is a function and rest all will be parameters

For more details: http://naveedramzan.com/codeigniter-url-rewriting/

Comment: how to get the url segments inside the product_lookup function?

Comment: `$this->uri->segment(3)` or `$this->input->get('variableName')`.

Comment: $last = $this->uri->total_segments();
  
    for($i=1;$i<=$last; $i++) {
        echo "<br>". $record_num = $this->uri->segment($i);
    }

this helped me thanks

Comment: instead of using loop. what if you get directly index -1.
For example `$this->url->segment($this->uri_total_segments()-1);` I think it will work

Comment: I need all the segments that's why loop used here :)

Comment: Or in CI way `$route[‘products/(:any)’] = “products/product_lookup”;`.